# Running npm run test in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, testing, dockerfile, continuous-integration

Using a builder to generate a smaller docker image, what would be a good way to run `npm run test`? I seems like running it in the Dockerfile after the build would make sense but maybe I'm missing something

Dockerfile

```
# Global args to persist through build stages
ARG docker_build_user
ARG docker_build_time
ARG docker_build_head
ARG docker_build_head_short
ARG docker_build_submodules_head

FROM node:8.9.4-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc g++ python

RUN npm install

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN npm run build

RUN rm -rf node_modules

RUN npm install

FROM node:8.9.4-alpine

# setup build metadata
ARG docker_build_user
ARG docker_build_time
ARG docker_build_head
ARG docker_build_head_short
ARG docker_build_submodules_head

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app .

ENV DOCKER_BUILD_USER $docker_build_user
ENV DOCKER_BUILD_TIME $docker_build_time
ENV DOCKER_BUILD_HEAD $docker_build_head
ENV DOCKER_BUILD_HEAD_SHORT $docker_build_head_short
ENV DOCKER_BUILD_SUBMODULES_HEAD $docker_build_submodules_head
ENV DOCKER_BUILD_DESCRIPTION This build was created by $docker_build_user at $docker_build_time from $docker_build_head_short
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV ENABLE_LOGGING=true

RUN echo "DESCRIPTION:${DOCKER_BUILD_DESCRIPTION}"

RUN chown -R 999:999 .
USER 999

# expose our service port
EXPOSE 8080

# Default is to run the server (should be able to run worker)
# Set env var in k8s or run : NPM_RUN_TASK (default is serve)
CMD ["/app/startup.sh"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you afford, you have already used `multistage build` for your `Dockerfile`, one stage for build, and one stage for package.

You use this because the final package stage do not need some build dependency for build, so you separate build to first stage. Then the things are same for test, your dockerfile structure will be something like next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Build stage
FROM node:8.9.4-alpine as builder
# ......
RUN npm install

# Test stage
FROM builder as test
# ......
RUN npm run test

# Package stage
FROM node:8.9.4-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app .
# ......
```

Then, the test stage still could use the built out things in build stage to test, but package stage will not have anything generated in test stage.

Some related guide refers to [this](https://www.qsstechnosoft.com/multi-stage-nodejs-build-with-docker-in-production/) and also [this](https://eridem.net/multistage-builds-for-nodejs), above is what other folks daily do for their nodejs project docker integration.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful! I used this in conjuction with the docker build --target test to execute the tests in the CI Pipeline